# How to pass objects from one page to another page in JSF without writing a converter

Tags: jsf, redirect, parameter-passing, jsf-2.2, view-scope

first of all sorry for my english. I have two pages in JSF2, one to list Passengers and another one to create/update passengers. I have also two @ViewScoped beans, one with the list of passengers and one for hold in pageB the selected passenger. I see the ways to pass the passenger through viewParam or @ManagedProperty but i don´t want to write a converter.

What i want to know if there is a way to pass the object from pageA to pageB without passing the id of the passenger and write a converter or without passing the id and then go to the DB to retrieve the passenger.
What i do and works is the following. I set in flash scope through setPropertyActionListener the selected object and navigate to pageB, in the @PostConstruct of the viewScopedBean i get the flashScope and retrieve the object. As i said, this works but i don´t know if it is correct. Here is the code
Page A:

```
<p:column width="10" style="text-align: center;">                    
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" action="editClientes?faces-redirect=true">                         
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{flash.pax}" value="#{row}"/> 
     </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

@PostConstruct of pageB bean

```
@PostConstruct
private void initBean(){          
    this.pax = (Passenger) JSFUtils.getFlashScope().get("pax"); 
    if(this.pax == null){
        this.pax = new Passenger();
    }           
}
```

Is this correct, or the correct way is to write a converter?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on whether you want the `/editClientes` request to be [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) ("bookmarkable") or not.

The flash approach is **not** idempotent. It's not possible to link/share/bookmark the `/editClientes` URL in order to edit a *specific* client. When the enduser copies this URL for sharing/bookmarking and re-executes the request on it (even though it's just pressing [enter] in browser's address bar), all the enduser would face is an empty edit form for a new client instead of the one the enduser initially selected via flash scope.

The request parameter approach is idempotent. The enduser is able to get **exactly** the same response everytime the enduser re-executes the request.

It's not our decision whether your `/editClientes` page should be idempotent or not. It's yours.

#### See also:

- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one/15523045#15523045)